# How tom Show 3D pie-chart in swift 4 in my app

Tags: ios, swift, pie-chart

I am trying to show a 3D pie-chart in my app  in swift 4.
but can't find any solution.does anyone help me or give me any suggestion please??

Comment: Do you want true 3D, or a perspective drawing that suggests 3D? True 3D requires a 3D rendering API like OpenGL or Metal. Creating a pie chart that looks like a 3D perspective projection would be simpler.

Comment: Your question is really to broad and vague for this site though. This site is for concrete help with code you've already written.

Comment: Use SceneKit.  Don't ask me how.

Answer (score -1):

```
private func createPieChart() -> SCNNode {
    let aNode = SCNNode()
    var total:Float = 0.0
    //let numRows = data.numberOfRows()
    let numColumns = data.numberOfColums()

    let i = 0
    for j in 0 ..< numColumns {
        let val = data.valueForIndexPath(row:i, column: j)
        total = total + val
    }

    var startDeg:Float = 0.0
    var startRad:Float = 0.0
    for j in 0 ..< numColumns {
        let val = data.valueForIndexPath(row:i, column: j)
        let pct = val*360.0/total
        startRad = Float(startDeg) * Float(M_PI) / Float(180.0)
        let endDeg = startDeg + pct - 1.0
        let endRad:Float = Float(endDeg) * Float(M_PI) / Float(180.0)
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath()
        circlePath.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
        circlePath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint.zero, radius: 20.0, startAngle:CGFloat(startRad), endAngle: CGFloat(endRad), clockwise: true)
        startDeg = endDeg + 1
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNShape(path:circlePath, extrusionDepth: 5.0))
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = data.colorForIndexPath(row: i, column: j)
        aNode.addChildNode(node)

    }

    return aNode
}
```

Comment: For the above code i am showing a 3D pie chart using SceneKit. 
Is it possible to click each slice of pie and clicking on this pie open another view??